# получение JSON данных с сервера и отрисовка в компоненте

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

1. цель вывести все города
2. Пример взят с оф документации  https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#how-can-i-make-an-ajax-call
3. мой json https://api.teleport.org/api/countries/
4. пример он-лайн https://codesandbox.io/s/q7rrxzon14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотя бы смотрели что вам приходит в ответ на запрос? Вы обращаетесь к несуществующему свойству из ответа.

> Список всех стран - `result._links['country:items']`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.teleport.org/api/countries/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
      (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            // items: result.items (???????)
            items: result._links['country:items']
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.name}>
              {item.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```